# What is the best way to kill the current ruler?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

To kill my current ruler, I made him a general and sent him many times in a one-man-army fighting against enemy's troops, but he doesn't die.

I can't find clear information about this subject. There is many contradictory tips on Internet : some say that you just need to send him alone to fight, like I did. Some other suggest it's better to send him in normal fights and the only thing matters is number of battles.

**What is the best way to kill the current ruler ?**

Is there an other way that the one I explained to do so ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is little else you can do. It is after all just a chance and a small one at that.

The simple act of making your ruler a general already significantly increases death chance(about twice as high). Battle do so as well. But the actual battle length isn't all that important. The longer a battle lasts, the more likely death becomes, in the end it evens out, as in the time a longer battle takes, you can do several suicide runs.

But even so, you are looking at chances of around 1%. Purposely killing a ruler or an heir simply is very difficult.

Also keep in mind, that a ruler/heir death in battle is a -1 stability hit, so if your ruler dies, you get -2 total (-1 from death in battle, -1 from ruler death)

Comment: I'd like to add that this trick doesn't work when you have a female leader, since you can't make her a general. There's no easy way to kill your queen, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way to give your ruler a chance to die not mention in Dulkan's answer.

You can take a cog with a single troop lead by your ruler. Find an ocean region that has no supply and will incur monthly damage to your cog. Let the cog sink. There is a chance for the ruler to die as well. This is useful to avoid the -1 stab hit from "battle".